# Oddness of UILable on customized table cell

Tags: objective-c

In my iphone app, I have a UITableView with customized cell. The text for one of the label on the cell could be quite long, and I would like it to wrap and clip to bound. I have tried couple of things, however the label still extend all way underneath the accessory icon.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom UITableViewCell then you can implement the `- (void) layoutSubviews` method and resize the UILabel in the cell.

Something like:

```
CGRect titleFrame = _title.frame;
NSString *currentText = [_title text];
CGSize size = [currentText sizeWithFont:_title.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(titleFrame.size.width, 50.0f) lineBreakMode:_title.lineBreakMode];
titleFrame.size.height = size.height;
_title.frame = titleFrame;
```

Where _title is the UILabel.

Answer (score 1):

I would add to elpri's answer that you don't need to go through all the trouble of creating a custom subclass of UITableViewCell.  Instead you can use tag's but the general approach is correct.

1. Calculate the size of the frame constraining it to a max size using `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`
2. Set width/height of your UILabel frame using the `calculatedSize.width` and `calculatedSize.height`

Using tags this would look like:

```
#define NAMELABEL_TAG 1

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ACellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:NAMELABEL_TAG];
    // the rest of your code to resize the frame can go here...
}
```

Also make sure to set the struts and springs correctly in interface builder so that it autoexpands when the device is rotated (assuming that is what you want).